# The ears of a rabbit are larger than ( ) of a fox

Tags: word-usage, pronouns

> The ears of a rabbit are larger than (     ) of a fox.

> 1 ones.   2 it.    3. those

I understand “those” come in the blank. How about “ones”? Why can’t “ones” come?

Comment: See also this related post on EL&U — ["The ones" or "those"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114834/the-ones-or-those)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ones** on its own is not correct, but **the ones** would be OK, though perhaps rather informal- fine for spoken English, but less acceptable in written English.

This [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=those%20of%20a%2C%20the%20ones%20of%20a%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthose%20of%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20ones%20of%20a%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthose%20of%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20ones%20of%20a%3B%2Cc0) shows that **those** is very much more common in written English. Judging by the author's names, most of the instances of **the ones** were written by non native English speakers.

Here is a typical example:

> The cognitive capabilities of complex organisms have little to do with **the ones** of a single cell.- *The Amazing Journey of Reason, Mario Alemi, 2019*

Answer (score 2):

You would at least want "the ones of a fox".  or "a fox's ones"

But while that may be correct grammar, only "those of a fox" is idiomatic.